# Problems with Responsive Menu & Layout

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a sticky menu set up so that on my desktop screen, the menu stays at the top no matter where the user is on the page. This works great on the computer, but not so great on a phone. My theme is a responsive theme so it adjusts to a phone screen pretty nicely, and the menu tab is condensed to a single drop down button on the phone. However, when you open the dropdown, all my menu bar tabs drop down into the first post content and are very hard to see and click on. I'm thinking this is because of the sticky menu that I set up.

I also have two ads set up outside my main content area. These overlap with the content area on a mobile phone. I need to keep these ads either pushed to the bottom of the content area, or hidden, on mobile view.

My site is www.beeandcompany.com. I would so appreciate if anyone would be able to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just edit the responsive css you have in your style.css. There is a line

```
@media screen and (max-width: 779px)
```

That will work on all resolutions smaller than 779px. There target your menu, and position it fixed to top left corner.

For instance

```
nav.lowermedia_add_sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #aaa;
z-index: 100;
}
```

You can edit it to your liking. Also you should make your menu toggle always visible. And those ads are overlapping your content. You should get someone to go through your design and fix stuff for responsive.

Comment: Thank you, that code helped fixed the menu problem on a phone. In regards to the ads, would there be a way to create a conditional that says if the screen is smaller than 779, do not show the ad?

Comment: You can inspect the divs they are in, and in the same way you targeted the menu on this resolution (with media query), you can just set those divs to `display:none`. I think it should be `ins.adsbygoogle{display:none;}` under the same media screen. Just be careful with ads by google. See if they have any policy about removing the ads on smaller resolutions, or see if they require them to always be visible.